# How to limit number in input tag of html through Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, scripting, pagination

Hey am working on a quote website project. To understand the question clearly see my html, css and Javascript.

***My Html***

```
<html>
<head>
<style>/* Main Status */

.pagable {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: var(--pageable-border);
  background: var(--pageable-background);
}
.status-copy-alert {
 position: relative;
 background-color: #18b495;
 color: #ffffff;
 padding: 10px 10px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 left: 8px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 0.05em;
 font-weight: 500;
 visibility: hidden;
}
.status-copy-alert:before{
 content:"";
 position: absolute;
 height: 10px;
 width: 10px;
 background-color: #18b495;
 left: -5px;
 transform: rotate(45deg);
 top: 39%;
}

.pagable .pagable-results {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0.25em;
}

.pagable .pagable-status {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0.25em;
  background: var(--pageable-status-background);
}

.pagable .pagable-actions {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-gap: 0.25em;
}
.pagable .pagable-actions input[name="page-curr"] {
  width: 3em;
}
.status-copy-alert {

 position: relative;

 background-color: #18b495;

 color: #ffffff;

 padding: 10px 10px;

 border-radius: 5px;

 left: -42px;

 text-transform: uppercase;

 letter-spacing: 0.05em;

 font-weight: 500;

 visibility: visible;
  
 opacity: 0;
  
 transition: left 0.4s, opacity 0.4s;

}

.animatedClass {
    left: 20px;
    opacity: 1;
}

.status-copy-alert:before{

 content:"";

 position: absolute;

 height: 10px;

 width: 10px;

 background-color: #18b495;

 left: -5px;

 transform: rotate(45deg);

 top: 39%;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="hindinj.html">caeman</a>
<div class="mainStatus">
   <h2 class="statusHeading">Latest English Status</h2>
<div class="allquotes"></div>
<div class="pagable-status">
  <label>Page <span class="page-no-curr"></span> of <span class="page-no-count"></span></label>
  <div class="pagination">
    <button class="page-btn-prev btn">PRE</button>
<span class="manho">1</span>
    <button class="page-btn-next btn">NEXT</button>
  </div>
      
 <input name="current-page" class="value-page" type="number" value="1" min="1">
<button class="jump-btn">Go</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

***My Javascript***

```
const resultEl = document.querySelector('.allquotes');
const pageCurr = document.querySelector('.manho')
const pageNoCurr = document.querySelector('.page-no-curr');
const pageNoCount = document.querySelector('.page-no-count')
const btnPrev = document.querySelector('.page-btn-prev');
const btnNext = document.querySelector('.page-btn-next');

let results = [];

const getResultCount = () => results.length;
const getPageSize = () => 12;
const getCurrPage = () => +pageCurr.innerText;
const getPageCount = () => Math.ceil(getResultCount() / getPageSize());

const pageResponse = (records, pageSize, page) =>
  (start => records.slice(start, Math.min(records.length, start + pageSize)))
  (pageSize * (page - 1));

const btnJump =  document.querySelector('.jump-btn');
const pageValue =  document.querySelector('.value-page');

const main = async() => {
  btnPrev.addEventListener('click', navPrev);
  btnNext.addEventListener('click', navNext);
  btnJump.addEventListener('click', navJump);

  results = await retrieveAllQuotes();
  updatePager(results);
  redraw();
};
const redraw = () => {
  resultEl.innerHTML = '';
  const paged = pageResponse(results, getPageSize(), getCurrPage());
  const contents = document.createElement('div');
  contents.classList.add("allStatus");
  const quotes = paged.map((record) => `<div class='latestatus'><p class='copytxt'>${record.quotes}</p><div> <button class="copystatus btn">Copy</button><span class="status-copy-alert hidden" id="status-copy-alert">Copied!</span></div></div>`);
  const quoteGroupNumer = Math.ceil(quotes.length / 2);
  const groups = Array(quoteGroupNumer).fill('').map((value, index) => {
    const groupQuoteFirst = quotes[2 * index]; // 0, 2, 4, 6
    const groupQuoteSecond = quotes[2 * index + 1] || ''; // 1, 3, 5, 7

    return `<div class="flex">${groupQuoteFirst}${groupQuoteSecond}</div>`;
  });

  contents.innerHTML = groups.join('');
  resultEl.append(contents);
};

const navPrev = (e) => {
  const pages = getPageCount();
  const curr = getCurrPage();
  const prevPage = curr > 1 ? curr - 1 : curr;
  pageCurr.innerText = prevPage;
  pageNoCurr.textContent = prevPage;
  redraw();
}

const navNext = (e) => {
  const pages = getPageCount();
  const curr = getCurrPage();
  const nextPage = curr < pages ? curr + 1 : curr;
  pageCurr.innerText = nextPage;
  pageNoCurr.textContent = nextPage;
  redraw();
}

const navJump = (e) => {
  const pages = getPageCount();
  const curr = getCurrPage();  
  pageCurr.innerText = pageValue.value;
  pageNoCurr.textContent = pageValue.value;
  redraw();
}

const updatePager = () => {
  const count = getPageCount();
  const curr = getCurrPage();
  pageCurr.innerText = curr > count ? 1 : curr;
  pageNoCurr.textContent = curr > count ? 1 : curr;
  pageNoCount.textContent = count;
};

const retrieveAllQuotes = async function() {
  return[{
      quotes: "1The cat is better than dog."
    },
    {
      quotes: "2Google is a open source library."
    },
    {
      quotes: "3Cats are better than ferrets."
    },
    {
      quotes: "4Love books."
    },
    {
      quotes: "5Life is short make it possible."
    },
    {
      quotes: "6The cat is better than dog"
    },
    {
      quotes: "7Google is a open source library."
    },
    {
      quotes: "8Cats are better than ferrets."
    },
    {
      quotes: "9Love books."
    },
    {
      quotes: "10Life is short make it possible."
    },
    {
      quotes: "1The cat is better than dog."
    },
    {
      quotes: "2Google is a open source library."
    },
    {
      quotes: "3Cats are better than ferrets."
    },
    {
      quotes: "4Love books."
    },
    {
      quotes: "5Life is short make it possible."
    },
    {
      quotes: "6The cat is better than dog"
    },
    {
      quotes: "7Google is a open source library."
    },
    {
      quotes: "8Cats are better than ferrets."
    },
    {
      quotes: "9Love books."
    },
    {
      quotes: "10Life is short make it possible."
    },
    {
      quotes: "1The cat is better than dog."
    },
    {
      quotes: "2Google is a open source library."
    },
    {
      quotes: "3Cats are better than ferrets."
    },
    {
      quotes: "4Love books."
    },
    {
      quotes: "5Life is short make it possible."
    },
    {
      quotes: "6The cat is better than dog"
    },
    {
      quotes: "7Google is a open source library."
    },
    {
      quotes: "8Cats are better than ferrets."
    },
    {
      quotes: "9Love books."
    },
    {
      quotes: "10Life is short make it possible."
    },
{
      quotes: "1The cat is better than dog."
    },
    {
      quotes: "2Google is a open source library."
    },
    {
      quotes: "3Cats are better than ferrets."
    },
    {
      quotes: "4Love books."
    },
    {
      quotes: "5Life is short make it possible."
    },
    {
      quotes: "6The cat is better than dog"
    },
    {
      quotes: "7Google is a open source library."
    },
    {
      quotes: "8Cats are better than ferrets."
    },
    {
      quotes: "9Love books."
    },
    {
      quotes: "10Life is short make it possible."
    },
]; 
}
document.querySelector('.allquotes').addEventListener(

  'click',

  function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    

    if (e.target && e.target.matches('.copystatus')) {

        const quote = e.target.parentNode.closest('.latestatus')

            .childNodes[0].textContent;
      
      const notify = e.target.nextSibling.closest('.status-copy-alert');
      notify.classList.add('animatedClass')
        setTimeout(() => {
            notify.classList.remove('animatedClass')
        }, 1000);

        const textArea = document.createElement('textarea');

        textArea.value = quote;

        document.body.appendChild(textArea);

        textArea.select();

        document.execCommand('Copy');

        textArea.remove();

    }

  },

  false

);
main();
```

Run the above code. You will see some quotes with excellent pagination. At the bottom of the page you can see a input tag and a ***Go*** button. This input and button is used to jump from one page to another. Just above of this you can see ***Page 1 of 4*** which indicates how many pages are there.

Now let us consider ***Page 1 of 4*** as ***Page 1 of Y***. Remember that the number 4 will gradually change when I add more quotes in JavaScript.

Now my problem is the input tag of the bottom. I needed it to limited to ***Y*** because the Y value may change everytime when I add quotes. Is there any  way so that if user enters a number higher than value ***Y*** it should be replaced to value Y and if the user enters lower than 1 it should be replaced to 1

I have tried different ways to solve this problem but none of them work and I am new to Javascript.

I hearty thanks for those who answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the number of possible values that the input tag can take using min and max attribute. But this restriction applies only when the user uses the control buttons of the input and not when types the number.
To control what the user types you have to use Javascript as in the snippet bellow. In addition, when the user press the go button you must check if the input tag has a value or is empty.
When the max value change (for example from 10 to 20) you must change also the max attribute of the input tag using this command `document.querySelector("input").max = 20;`

```js
document.querySelector("input").oninput = (e) => {
    let input = e.target;
    if (input.value != "") { //otherwise the user cannot delete the current value
      let value = parseInt(input.value); 
      if (value > parseInt(input.max)) input.value = input.max;
      else if (value < parseInt(input.min)) input.value = input.min;
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" value="1" min="1" max="10">
<button class="jump-btn">Go</button>
```

Comment: Is there any way so that I should not change the max value every time when I add quotes to my website.

Comment: If you don't change the max value every time the user could add a value outside of the range with the controls that the number input tag has. The javascript code only controls the case when the user try to type a number and not when change the value with the spinners. This is controlled by the html and the min and max attributes.

Comment: Is ther any way so that the max value is equal to the pageNoCount(in JavaScript)

Comment: Yes. You can add in `updatePager` after the `pageNoCount.textContent = count;` the below command: `pageValue.max = count;`. So, every time the pager is updated the max value of the input will get the value of the new count.

Comment: Additionally, why do you use for example `const getPageSize = () => 12;` and not `const getPageSize = 12;`? Is there any reason to do it in this way? You can use a simple variable instead of a function.